# Accessing functionalities of chaincode accross organization

Tags: distributed-computing, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

From the view of large scale distributed systems If a network over a channel x has 1 Manufacturer organization and 1000 testing organization. All testing orgs have their own functionalites in their chain code now If Manufacturer org has to access a function of testing org x then how that has to happen where all the chaincode needs to be installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If manufacturer chaincode is going to invoke chaincodes of testing organizations by sending transaction for endorsement to its own peer, at minimum all chaincodes has to be installed on manufacturer endorsing peer. Therefore all chaincodes of testing orgs has to be installed on set of peers which will serve as endorsing peers for manufacturer chaincode.

Comment: so If  chaincodes of all org are available on all endorsing peers I expect if any org goes down their chaincode shouldn't get executed but in this case it executes right?

Comment: Yes it will be executed, but you can define an endorsement policy which will require endorsement from certain org, therefore if orgs down transaction won't be validated. As a result tx won't be committed.